# Support for multiple blog layouts in the same wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is there a way to add support for multiple blog page layouts for a wordpress site.  I would like to be able to somehow choose 
the layout I want for the post as I create/edit the post.  I know for the pages scenario, you can create page templates and 
just select the one you want from a dropdown.  Is there a way to achieve this same functionality for posts and if so, how?

The current site I am working on is using the klasik framework and the themeforest consult-ts template.  I do not know if that makes a difference.

Comment: Is this the default wordpress "post" post type, or is this a template for a custom post type?

Comment: It should be default.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress provides a template hierarchy which gives you the flexibility to create custom layouts for posts, pages, archives, etc. To create a custom layout for a specific blog post, you would name the template single-{post-type}-{slug}.php

You can find out more about the template hierarchy [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)